# How to make Firestore query during SSR

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, server-side-rendering

I would like to fetch data from Firestore during server side rendering. I know I could use [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) (and attach the token to the request's headers) but I don't want to write REST requests on server side and then duplicate the same requests on client side using [standard Firestore queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries). On client I prefer standard queries (no REST) because of the realtime updates. And I would like to reuse the queries from client also on the server (even without the benefit of realtime updates).

I validate the token manually on the server:

```js
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { initializeApp, getApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(config);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie);
// => token verified: decodedIdToken.userId = "xxx"
```

But when I want to perform a query:

```js
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'myCollection'));
```

I get error:

```json
{
  "code": "permission-denied",
  "name": "FirebaseError"
}
```

Firestore rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

On client side the error could be solved using `onAuthStateChanged` but I can't use this listener on server.

Is there any way to run Firestore queries with manually verified token?

Comment: Can you provide the Firestore rules for your project based on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)?

Comment: @RobertG Question updated with the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to replicate your error. You're getting this error because you're trying to use client SDK instead of `firebase-admin`.

Here's the sample code for your reference:

```js
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(config);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

// const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie);
// => token verified: decodedIdToken.userId = "xxx"

// const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'myCollection'));
db.collection("myCollection").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

I've used `version 8` (commonJS) instead of `version 9` (modular) as `firebase-admin` still uses the dot notation syntax.

```js
[sampleQuery]  =>  { test: 'testing' }
```

Here's the link on [how to get all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).

Here's another reference on [upgrading to Node.js SDK Admin SDK v10 (modular SDK)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10).

---

**Update:**

If you wanted to use the Firestore Security Rules, you need to use custom signed tokens, you need to pass it to `signInWithCustomToken` so that the client auth can sign in.

Below is a sample code for your reference:

```js
import { getAuth, signInWithCustomToken } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
signInWithCustomToken(auth, token)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
```

A new user will be created and linked all their credentials and the new account will be stored as part of your project, and will be used to identify a user across every app in your project.

You can also allow a user to sign out by calling `signOut`:

```js
import { getAuth, signOut } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
signOut(auth).then(() => {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error happened.
});
```

You can check this documentation on [authenticating with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth#authenticate-with-firebase) for additional information.

Comment: I want to use client SDK also on the server. The reason is I want to run the queries on behalf of the logged user in order to apply Firestore rules.
So I imagine I need to somehow "sign" the requests from my server to Firestore with client's token.

Comment: @PetrK., please check as I've updated my answer. Thank you.